# How do you use health items in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I played Borderlands 1, but it's been a long time. I've searched through the menus, and I can't see how I use any of the red health items. I know I must have some, because when I approach new ones they say "Full".  Help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The health items are instantly applied in Borderlands 2 (unlike Borderlands 1, where there were some medkits that had to be applied from the inventory). They're useless if you're already at full health.

Comment: But remember where you see them, because you may need to find them in a hurry in a minute. :)